# Running total with Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

We would like to convert the following MySQL query to Slick. Is it possible? I couldn't find an example with `SET` or "running total" anywhere.

Select some elements from `oldtransactions` and add a balance column with running total. From the result, select a specific transaction by transaction id and show the balance at that point.

```
SET @runtot =0; 

SELECT balance 
FROM   (SELECT clno, 
               acno1, 
               ( @runtot := @runtot + r.amount ) AS balance 
        FROM   (SELECT * 
                FROM   oldtransactions 
                WHERE  ( acno1 = '' 
                          OR acno2 = '' )) AS t 
        ORDER  BY trtime ASC) AS final 
WHERE  tt_id = '123'
```